# Pingdom monitoring tool detecting HTTP 302 Found responses intermittently

Tags: php, http, redirect, monitoring, pingdom

I am experiencing intermittent issues when using the [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) monitoring tool to check the status of my website.

Every 10-15 minutes I get an alert to say that a 302 has been found. What I can't understand is - i'm not doing any 302 temporary redirects. I am, however, doing 301 redirects (in certain circumstances).

Could this be a false positive from Pingdom?

Also, I have a redirect in code that does this. Would not specifying the HTTP response code
cause an issue here?

```
header('Location: http://www.ayrshireminis.com');
exit();
```

The Pingdom data:

```
Request 1
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)
Host: www.ayrshireminis.com

Received header
302 Found
Date: Tue, 24 Jul 2012 13:13:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: prev_session_id=2a7001f5caa79bd36995953bf4853675; expires=Thu, 23-Aug-2012 13:13:25 GMT; path=/; domain=ayrshireminis.com
Location: http://www.ayrshireminis.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a cookie is being set on the response, then redirecting you to the same page.    Because Pingdom uses a number of different monitoring sources, that cookie redirect behavior will cause a lot of problems.  Then again, you may need it for actual website visitors.

Rather than monitor the root of the webpage, I would recommend creating a separate /status page just for Pingdom that:

1. Doesn't set or use cookies
2. Performs a cheap end-to-end health check of the application and backing services
3. Returns a 200 response code only if everything checks out OK

Comment: I like the idea of the "status" page that you have suggested. The only problem is that I would need to mimic actual functionality, as close as possible to the homepage, on the "status" page. I would imagine that a homepage is used for Pingdom testing as it is the best test available, as obviously it is the first page a user hits. I'm also interested by your comment on being redirected to the _same_ page - would this be an issue? Does this constitute a 302 redirect?

Comment: The 302 redirect you are seeing is due to a cookie being set by your PHP framework (see the Set-Cookie header).  The Location header shows you are being sent to the same page that you originally requested -- now with a cookie.  Because the next request has this cookie, you should receive a normal 200 response code.  For Pingdom to work properly, you need to prevent this auto cookie generation/redirect.  It's probably a setting in your PHP framework.  I would recommend testing it with a /status page just because you may _want_ the cookie behavior for most visitors.